# If life tells you no …

Tags: expresiones, modismos

… tell it "no nor nothing"?

"Si la vida te dice no, dile no ni ná"

I assume "ná" is "nothing," but the overall meaning escapes me.

Is it anything like "[when life gives you lemons](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25979/spanish-version-for-when-life-gives-you-lemons)"?  (Doesn't seem so to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used to encourage optimism and be positive about life when someone feels like a victim of misfortune and rebels against that reality. It's a triple negative that means 'I don't accept that.' I refuse to believe that what happens is out of your control.

- "Say 'yeah, right' when life says no." (sarcastically)
  *Sí, como no(burlándose en la desgracia, con sorna).*
- "Say 'yes, I can.' when life says no."
  *Sí, puedo con eso (en rebeldía)*

ná = nada = nothing;
ni = nor;
no = no;
¡No ni ná! = The hell I'm not! = yeah, right!

Answer (score 1):

[José María Pérez Orozco](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Mar%C3%ADa_P%C3%A9rez_Orozco) was a writer and professor of Spanish Language and Literature, and a firm defender of the Andalusian way of speaking. In [an interview](https://www.canalsur.es/television/no-ni-na-tres-negaciones-que-son-una-rotunda-afirmacion-en-andaluz/1554357.html) in the Andalusian regional TV channel, Canal Sur, he stated the following:

> Resulta que cuando tú le preguntas a un amigo tuyo, por ejemplo, «Antonio, ¿este año vas a ir al [Rocío](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romer%C3%ADa_de_El_Roc%C3%ADo)?», y dice: «No ni *na*». Y si tú te fijas bien, esa frase son tres negaciones: «No-ni-*na*». Y es la mayor afirmación que hay en el andaluz. Cuando una persona te dice «No ni *na*», no te quepa duda de que es que sí. [...] Cuando tú dices «no ni *na*», estás diciendo: la primera, «no voy a dejar de ir al Rocío»; «ni aunque llueva, truene o ventee»; «*na* me va a impedir que vaya». Todo eso resumido en tres sílabas.

The most important thing to understand is that *no ni na* is the biggest affirmation a person can say, similar to «que no qué va», despite the expression being three negations. *No ni na* is without a trace of doubt a "yes". So your sentence can be understood just as:

> If life tells you no, you say "yes".

| Spanish | English |
| --- | --- |
| **no** voy a dejar de ir al Rocío | I shall go to El Rocío whatever it happens |
| **ni** aunque llueva, truene o ventee | even if it rains, storms or the wind blows |
| **na** me va a impedir que vaya | nothing's going to stop me |

Note that the previous sentence is just an example of the true meaning behind the *no ni na* expression, and not its true origin.

Comment: In redneck, “hold my beer.”  :-)

Comment: @WGroleau in Spain it is becoming quite popular "sujétame el [cubata](http://dle.rae.es/cubata)".